# fvtk no attribute white

Tags: python, module

I used the example code in http://nipy.org/dipy/examples_built/segment_quickbundles.html; however I got module import error. Ninja said:

> fvtk.add(r, fvtk.line(streamlines, fvtk.white, opacity=1, linewidth=3))
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'white'

Answer (score 0):

Yeah - that was an error that existed in the documentation. It should have been:

```
fvtk.colors.white
```